# How to make shorter path for a nested resourceful route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rest, routes, restful-url

I have categories and categories have entries.
The common path for the "show" resourceful route for this case will be: **/categories/:category_id/entries/:entry_id**

I can make this path more friendly with [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), so it will look like:
**/categories/:category_name/entries/:entry_name**

But finally I want the path more simpler like:
**/:category_name/:entry_name**.
*Is this possible and how? 
Will such path (and its implementation) still be resourceful (RESTful) ?
Will such path be found faster than 2nd one by any search engine (like google, etc.)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try simple:

```
resources :categories, path: '' do
  resources :entries, path: ''
end
```

?

Comment: :) Big thanks! I did not know about this... After your answer, searched google once more and found this info at the official rails api doc... Somewhy I thought that all I need I can find at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Do you know whether such "short" path can be found "faster" by google? so my site will be closer to top lines found by google...

Comment: I can't think as google does, but it's obvious for me that adding unnecessary keywords in your url shouldn't give you more points (and it also can't make your visitors happier trying to enter your too-big-to-fit-in-screen-url on their mobile devices). But url isn't all you need: you also have to keep in mind using meta-tags, proper and descriptive titles, alternative texts for your images and so on.

Comment: If you want more thoughts about SEO from google itself check: http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf